# Laminas (Zend, zf3) manually setting Route, so that including MVC-Application in separate Software, e.g. Wordpress is possible

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, zend-framework, laminas

So, I'm looking for a quick and lazy way to use a Laminas **MVC**-Application with its complete functionality (Controller, ViewRenderer, etc) in Wordpress.

This works in terms of that the the MVC-App inits and runs:

```php
<?php
require '/PATH/TO/LAMINAS-MVC-APP/public/app.php';
```

However, it always triggers a 404-Error. So, my approach would be to manipulate the Route manually. What is the best practice? Where and when can I set it? Maybe in one of the Bootstrap-Events?

This is how my `app.php` (adaption of the regular `/public/index.php` of Laminas MVC) looks like:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
use Laminas\Mvc\Application;

/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
// Composer autoloading
include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$container = require __DIR__ . '/../config/container.php';


$app = $container->get('Application');
ob_start();
$app->run();
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Use $out in Wordpress!!
```